# increase and decrease gui not increasing not sure were im going wrong

Tags: java, eclipse

help trying to make an increase and decrease button that increase and decrease  numbers on a panel just not working for me trying to get actionPerformed and the action listener isnt working could someone give me guidance  `

```
public class IncrDecPanel extends JPanel  
{




private int INITIAL_NUMBER = 50;
private JButton Incr, Dec;
private JLabel label;
private JPanel ButtonPanel; 
private int number;

public IncrDecPanel()
{ 


    number = INITIAL_NUMBER;

    label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(number));

    Incr = new JButton("Incr");
    Dec = new JButton("Dec");


     JButton IncrButton = new JButton("Increment");
     IncrButton.addActionListener (new IncrListener());


    JButton DecButton = new JButton("Decrement");
     DecButton.addActionListener(new DecListener());



      ButtonPanel = new JPanel();
      ButtonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 40));
      ButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
      ButtonPanel.add(Incr);
      ButtonPanel.add(Dec);

      12
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 80));
      setBackground(Color.black);
      add(label);
      add(ButtonPanel);
}


 private class IncrListener implements ActionListener
   {

      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
      {
         label.setText (Integer.toString (++number));
      }
   }
         private class DecListener implements ActionListener
         {

            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
            {
               label.setText (Integer.toString (--number));
            }

      }
 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the `ActionListeners` to the wrong buttons.
You're created the buttons `Incr` and `Dec`, then you add your listeners to `IncrButton` and `DecButton`, before adding `Incr` and `Dec` to your JPanel. Just assign your listeners to your first buttons after you create them, like:

```
    Incr = new JButton("Incr");
    Dec = new JButton("Dec");

    Incr.addActionListener(new IncrListener());
    Dec.addActionListener(new DecListener());
```

Hope this helps. :)